# Data structure for storing debugging symbols

Tags: data-structures, associative

I need to store all debugging symbols (for simplicity, only function names + addresses).
I do not have function sizes.
Like:

> _printf 0x1234
>
> _fprintf 0x1255
>
> _scanf 0x1300

I need a very fast algorithm for determining function name by address, for example:

> 0x1258 - _fprintf+0x3

Simple STL map is far from useful. What data structure will fit here?

Comment: I probably need segment tree?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map word-sized keys to a string table? An endian [patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) should be both time and space efficient. One bit in the int tag per branch. Also known an *Int Maps* in some communities.

Comment: Oh no, difference between values are not string lengths, but function lengths in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It simpler that I thought: just use STL map::lower_bound().